# Botones + Intents con multiples destinos

Tags: java, android, android-intent

A partir de una activity con datos de un sensor y dos botones, uno para mostrar gráficas y otro para mostrar sus parámetros.

**Pregunta**:

Cómo hacer para que lleve a la activity que le corresponde cuando se haga un clic sobre uno de los botones. Parece obvio, pero hay que tener en cuenta que el objeto que se abre puede ser o "Barómetro" o  "TemperaturaHuemdadDht22" y que hasta que no se abre la activity "InsertarObjeto.java" la activity no sabe si vas a abrir  "Barómetro" o "Temperatura&Huemdad".

**Funcionamiento de la APP:**

*ActividadListaObjetos.java*

A partir de una lista, cuando hago clic sobre uno de sus componentes, abre dicho componente en otra pantalla y me da todos los datos de dicho componente. Estos componentes están en una base de datos externa MySql y se sincroniza con una SQlite interna para después poblar con los datos sincronizados la lista y tabla. En el ejemplo mostrado hay dos componentes, pero podrían ser 100 o 50...

### [image: pantalla lista "ActividadListaObjetos.java"]

*Activity "ActividadInsercionObjetos.java"*

Cuando se hace clic sobre uno de los objetos de la lista anterior la App te lleva a otra actividad que te muestra los datos generales de dicho objeto en concreto y dos botones. Si se hace clic sobre uno de ellos

a) Botón = Te lleva a Una gráfica con los datos de dicho Objeto ("GraficaTemperaturaHuemdad.java" o "GraficaBarometro.java")

b) Botón = Te lleva a una tabla que se llena con los datos de dicho Objeto ("Barometro.java" o "ResultadoTemperaturaHumedadDht22.java".

**Nota: Un Objeto puede tener el mismo idObjeto que otro, se diferencian por su nombre no por su IdObjeto, ya que el IdObjeto describe el identificador de una placa base que abriga varios sensores.*

**Barometro**

[image: Activity "ActividadInsercionObjetos.java"]

**TemperaturaHumedadDht22**

[image: TemperaturaHumedadDht22]
Cuando se hace clic sobre el botón "acceso datos del sensor" la app debería llevar a los datos que corresponden al sensor mostrado, que bien puede ser :

a) Barometro.java

[image: Barometro.java]

b) TemperaturaHumedadDht22.java

[image: TemperaturaHumedadDht22]

**Código :**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

public class ActividadInsercionObjeto extends AppCompatActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, View.OnClickListener {
// Referencias UI
private TextView campodescripcionNombre;
private TextView campoMarca;
private TextView campoModelo;
private TextView campoCorreo;
private TextView campoIdObjeto;
private Button accesodata;
private Button accesotabla;
public final static String EXTRA_ID = "idObjeto";
public EditText IdentidadObjeto;


// Clave del uri del objeto como extra
public static final String URI_OBJETO = "extra.uriObjeto";

private Uri uriObjeto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_insercion_objeto);


    // Encontrar Referencias UI
    campodescripcionNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo_descripcion_nombre);
    campoMarca = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo_marca);
    campoModelo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo_modelo);
    campoCorreo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo_correo);
    campoIdObjeto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo_idObjeto);



    accesodata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accesodata);
    accesodata.setOnClickListener(this);
    accesotabla = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accesotabla);
    accesotabla.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Determinar si es detalle
    String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra(URI_OBJETO);
    if (uri != null) {
        setTitle(R.string.titulo_actividad_editar_objeto);
        uriObjeto = Uri.parse(uri);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);
    }



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_insercion_objeto, menu);

    // Verificación de visibilidad acción eliminar
    if (uriObjeto != null) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.accion_eliminar).setVisible(true);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.accion_confirmar:
            insertar();
            break;
        case R.id.accion_eliminar:
            eliminar();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void insertar() {

    // Extraer datos de UI
    String descripcionNombre = campodescripcionNombre.getText().toString();
    String marca = campoMarca.getText().toString();
    String modelo = campoModelo.getText().toString();
    String correo = campoCorreo.getText().toString();
    String IdentidadObjeto = campoIdObjeto.getText().toString();



    // Validaciones y pruebas de cordura
    if (!esNombreValido(descripcionNombre)) {
        TextInputLayout mascaraCampoNombre = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.mascara_campo_nombre);

        // esta linea la he añadido, si da fallo eliminar. Sujerida por corrector
        assert mascaraCampoNombre != null;
        // esta linea la he añadido, si da fallo eliminar. Sujerida por corrector fin
        mascaraCampoNombre.setError("este campo no puede quedar vacio");
    } else {

        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

        // Verificación: ¿Es necesario generar un id?
        if (uriObjeto == null) {
            valores.put(Objetos.ID_OBJETO, Objetos.generarIdObjeto());
        }
        valores.put(Objetos.DESCRIPCION_NOMBRE, descripcionNombre);
        valores.put(Objetos.MARCA_MARCA, marca);
        valores.put(Objetos.MODELO, modelo);
        valores.put(Objetos.CORREO, correo);
        valores.put(Objetos.VERSION, UTiempo.obtenerTiempo());

        // Iniciar inserción|actualización
        new TareaAnadirObjeto(getContentResolver(), valores).execute(uriObjeto);



        finish();
    }
}

private boolean esNombreValido(String nombre) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(nombre);
}

private void eliminar() {
    if (uriObjeto != null) {
        // Iniciar eliminación
        new TareaEliminarObjeto(getContentResolver()).execute(uriObjeto);
        finish();
    }
}


private void poblarViews(Cursor data) {
    if (!data.moveToNext()) {
        return;
    }

    // Asignar valores a UI
    campodescripcionNombre.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.DESCRIPCION_NOMBRE));
    campoMarca.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.MARCA_MARCA));
    campoModelo.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.MODELO));
    campoCorreo.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.CORREO));
    campoIdObjeto.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.ID_OBJETO));

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, uriObjeto, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    poblarViews(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}



   // @Override
   public void onClick (View v) {


           if (v == accesotabla) {

               Intent i = new Intent(ActividadInsercionObjeto.this, GraficaHumedadTemperatura.class);

               i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
               startActivity(i);

           }

       if (v == accesodata) {

           Intent i = new Intent(ActividadInsercionObjeto.this, **DEPENDEQUESENSORSEHIZOELCLIC.class**);
               i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
               startActivity(i);

       }
   }


static class TareaAnadirObjeto extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {
    private final ContentResolver resolver;
    private final ContentValues valores;

    public TareaAnadirObjeto(ContentResolver resolver, ContentValues valores) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
        this.valores = valores;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Uri... args) {
        Uri uri = args[0];
        if (null != uri) {
            /*
            Verificación: Si el cobjeto que se va a actualizar aún no ha sido sincronizado,
            es decir su columna 'insertado' = 1, entonces la columna 'modificado' no debe ser
            alterada
             */
            Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, new String[]{Objetos.INSERTADO}, null, null, null);

            if (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {

                // Verificación de sincronización
                if (UConsultas.obtenerInt(c, Objetos.INSERTADO) == 0) {
                    valores.put(Objetos.MODIFICADO, 1);
                }

                valores.put(Objetos.VERSION, UTiempo.obtenerTiempo());
                resolver.update(uri, valores, null, null);
            }

        } else {
            resolver.insert(Objetos.URI_CONTENIDO, valores);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

static class TareaEliminarObjeto extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {
    private final ContentResolver resolver;

    public TareaEliminarObjeto(ContentResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Uri... args) {

        /*
        Verificación: Si el registro no ha sido sincronizado aún, entonces puede eliminarse
        directamente. De lo contrario se marca como 'eliminado' = 1
         */
        Cursor c = resolver.query(args[0], new String[]{Objetos.INSERTADO}
                , null, null, null);

        int insertado;

        if (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
            insertado = UConsultas.obtenerInt(c, Objetos.INSERTADO);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        if (insertado == 1) {
            resolver.delete(args[0], null, null);
        } else if (insertado == 0) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put(Objetos.ELIMINADO, 1);
            resolver.update(args[0], valores, null, null);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta encontrada por : [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007)

```
 if (v == accesodata) {

           String nombre = campodescripcionNombre.getText().toString();
           if (nombre.equals("Barometro")) {

               Intent i = new Intent(ActividadInsercionObjeto.this, Barometro.class);
               i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
               startActivity(i);

           } else {
               Intent i = new Intent(ActividadInsercionObjeto.this, TemperaturaHumedadDht22.class);
               i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
               startActivity(i);
           }
       }
   }
```

También podría ser:

```
if (v == accesodata) {
Class c = null;
String nombre = campodescripcionNombre.getText().toString();
if (nombre.equals("Barometro") { // TODO: figure out what you should check 
    c = Barometro.class;
} else {
    c = TemperaturaHuemdadDht22.class;
} 
Intent i = new Intent(ActividadInsercionObjeto.this, c);
i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```